# Python 3 - Class variable is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

Here I'm not able to access the class variable inside a Python's
**list comprehension**.

```
class Student:
  max_year = 18
  year_choice = [i for i in range(100) if i > max_year]

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    print (self.year_choice)

Student('Blah')
```

But it's working fine in Python 2.

```
../workspace$ python student.py
[19, 20, 21, 22, 2.... 99]
```

But getting an error in Python 3.

```
../workspace$ python student.py
File "student.py", line 18, in <listcomp>
year_choice = [i for i in range(100) if i > max_year]
NameError: name 'max_year' is not defined
```

from debugging this When I changed 
below statement

`[i for i in range(100) if i > max_year]`

to this

```
[i for i in range(max_year)] # don't look too much into it ;)
```

working fine.
Why I'm not able to access class variable inside **if/else list comprehension**?

Comment: Ok, that's seriously weird. ;) Also, it's nothing to do with the `if` inside the list comp. This doesn't work either: `[max_year-i for i in range(max_year)]`

Comment: Yes from @py_dude Answer, We can define self.max_year It's shared with class and instance of this class. not only for this example. But here I'm curious to know why we can't access the class variable inside if/else list comprehension?

Comment: Good question but it is still a duplicate ;-)

Comment: as for the `range(max_year)` it works because the `range(max_year)` is evaluated *outside* the scope created for the list comprehension, but the `if` clause is evaluated *within* the new scope.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer that illustrates Antti Haapala's explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that this line

```
year_choice = [i for i in range(100) if i > max_year]
```

works in Python 2 but not in Python 3 is that in Python 3 list comprehensions create a new scope, and the `max_year` class attribute isn't in that scope. In Python 2, a list comprehension doesn't create a new scope, it runs in the context of the surrounding code. That was originally done for performance reasons, but a lot of people found it confusing, so it was changed in Python 3, bringing list comprehensions into line with generator expressions, and set and dict comprehensions.

AFAIK, there is no simple way in Python 3 to access a class attribute inside a list comprehension that is running in the outer context of a class, rather than inside a method. You can't refer to it with `Student.max_year`, since at that point the `Student` class doesn't exist.

However, there really is no point having that list comprehension there anyway. You can create the list you want more compactly, and more efficiently. For example:

```
class Student(object):
    max_year = 18
    year_choice = list(range(max_year + 1, 100))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print (self.year_choice)

Student('Blah')
```

**output**

```
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

That code produces the same output on Python 2 and Python 3.

I've changed the class signature to

```
class Student(object):
```

so that it creates a new-style class in Python 2 (in Python 3 all classes are new-style).

---

The reason that `[i for i in range(max_year)]` can get around this restriction is that an iterator is created from `range(max_year)` which is then passed as the argument to the temporary function which runs the list comprehension. So it's equivalent to this code:

```
class Student(object):
    max_year = 18
    def _listcomp(iterator):
        result = []
        for i in iterator:
            result.append(i)
        return result

    year_choice = _listcomp(iter(range(max_year + 1, 100)))
    del _listcomp

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self.year_choice)

Student('Blah')
```

Many thanks to Antti Haapala for this explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me solve this exact issue. If you have a reason for keeping the class variables as they are, you can hack around this occurrence in a more general way by using a second layer of list comprehension and wrapping the required class variables in tuples to force them into the scope, like so:
`year_choice = [[i for i in d[0]  if i > d[1]] for d in (range(100), max_year)][0]`